# How can i use a nestjs service function in a typescript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, cron, nestjs

I have a service with a specific function and i have a controller with a route that executes the service function but now i need to execute that function in a cron job, i am using node-cron library. The thing is if i have call that service function in another typescrip file?

This is my typescript file where i have a cron job and i try to execute the service function.

cronJob.ts

```
@Injectable() export class SslCronJob { // @Inject(SslService) // private sslService: SslService;

constructor (
    @Inject(SslService)
    private readonly sslService: SslService
) {}

async upload() {
    await this.sslService.upload()
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', async () => {
        console.log('running a task every minute');
        try {
            await this.sslService.upload()
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error: ", err)
        }
    });

}
}
```

and i try to execute this from main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
    ...
    ...
    const sslService: SslService = new SslService()
    let sslCron = new SslCronJob(sslService);
    sslCron.upload()
}
```

[image]

but i have this error when executes it, can access to model property.

Answer (score 0):

`Cron.schedule` handles the callback in a separate context, hence it is not aware of the `this.sslService`.

Try using [`TaskScheduling`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/task-scheduling) module of NestJs to perform this. This will look something like this

```
 @Cron('* * * * * *')
  handleCron() {
    await this.sslService.upload()
  }
```

Also in `main.ts` if you want to get the service use

```
const sslService: SslService = app.get(SslService)
let sslCron = new SslCronJob(sslService);
sslCron.upload()
```

If you use the task scheduling module then you wont be needing this execution in main.ts

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, with node-cron and modifying the way of executing in main.ts as you tell me it works correctly. Also, thanks for the TaskScheduling thing, I've already been reviewing it and it's super good.

Comment: What do you mean by separate instance?

Comment: @AluanHaddad sorry! meant to say `context` instead of `instance`